# Best way to query for items with the most "upvotes"

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on adding up and down votes to some items in the database, and displaying them ordered by the highest upvotes.  How would this query look like?

How can I make something like this in SQL?

```
SELECT col1 col2 FROM some_table WHERE "highest number of upvotes"
```

Comment: What does your schema look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `upvotes` is a field in your table, you can use ORDER BY and optionally a LIMIT:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM some_table
ORDER BY upvotes DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: shouldn't you compare downvotes with upvotes? The question with the highest upvotes could also have the same ammount of downvotes

Comment: `ORDER BY (upvotes - downvotes) DESC`  
Much slower, though, in a big table, because every value has to be computed. You might want to create a redundant field and update it per trigger or create an [INDEX on the expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-expressional.html).